# Change of variables formula for transformation of multivariate normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, bayesian, change-of-variable, multivariate-statistical-analysis

Given a multivariate normal distribution $X \sim N(\beta, \Sigma)$, where $\Sigma$ is positive definite, how would I go about finding the joint distribution of $y_i=-exp(-x_i)$? It is straightforward for the univariate case using the change of variables formula, but I'm not sure whether I'm applying it correctly for the multivariate case.

The case I need this for is the following: I have a multivariate normal prior over two random variables, and have updated my beliefs following a number of draws. The distribution of $X$ is my posterior distribution. I now want to find the distribution of my utility $u(x)$, where $u(x)=-\exp(-x)$.

As example, consider the bivariate case:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2
\end{pmatrix}
= g\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-\exp(-x_1) \\
-\exp(-x_2)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The function $g$ has domain $(-\infty, \infty)$ and range $(-\infty,0)$ so it should be applicable.

The inverse function $g^{-1}$ would then be $-\log(-y_i)$ and the determinant of the Jacobian of this inverse matrix $$J=\begin{pmatrix}-1/y_1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1/y_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1/\exp(-x_1) & 0 \\ 0 & 1/\exp(-x_2)\end{pmatrix}$$

Would the resulting distribution simply be
$$p(y(x))=\frac{\exp \left(-0.5(x-\mu)\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)\right)}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^2|\Sigma|}}\times |J|$$

Or am I going wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The joint distribution function of $Y_i=-\exp(-X_i)$ is
$$\tag{1}
\mathbb P\Big\{Y_1\le y_1,...,Y_n\le y_n\Big\}=\mathbb P\Big\{X_1\le -\log(- y_1),...,X_n\le -\log(-y_n)\Big\}\,.
$$
Write $\Phi(x_1,...,x_n)$ for the CDF of the $n$-dimensional normal distribution $N(\beta,\Sigma)$.
The RHS of (1) is then
$$
\Phi\Big(-\log(-y_1),...,-\log(-y_n)\Big)\,.
$$
The PDF you are looking for is the obtained by differentiating w.r.t. each $y_i$.
By the chain rule this is
$$
\varphi\Big(-\log(-y_1),...,-\log(-y_n)\Big)\frac{(-1)^n}{y_1\cdot...\cdot y_n}\,,\quad y_i<0\,,
$$
where $\varphi(x_1,...,x_n)$ is the PDF of $N(\beta,\Sigma)$.